# Flex DateChooser in Japanese Style

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How I can change the display of Month and Year display to Japanese style (i.e. Year Month) as in Header of Flex Date Chooser. What I would like to convert the style 
8月　2011年　to 2011年　8月.

[image: Flex Date Chooser]

Code I used to do that,

```
dateFrom.dayNames = ['日', '月', '火', '水', '木', '金', '土'];

dateFrom.monthNames = ['１月','２月','３月','４月','５月','６月','７月','８月','９月','10月','１１月','１２月'];

dateFrom.yearSymbol = "年";
```

where dateFrom is the id of the DateField.

Comment: This has noting to do with anythng, but the half-width "10" for October stands out like a sore thumb. You should change it to double-width :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you should change date format in locale settings. When the year preceedes the month, `DateChooser` shows labels accordingly.

1) Quick patch - set it manually on app start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    preinitialize="application1_preinitializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function application1_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var array:Array = resourceManager.getLocales();
                for each (var locale:String in array)
                {
                    var shared:IResourceBundle = resourceManager.getResourceBundle(locale, "SharedResources");
                    shared.content["dateFormat"] = "YYYY/MM/DD";
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:DateChooser />
</mx:Application>
```

2) Proper way - create locale resource with date format:

```
dateFormat=YYYY/MM/DD
```

More on this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_6.html